# How to Trigger Jenkins Job When any git branch from a list has a Commit

Tags: git, jenkins, github

My requirement involves triggering a Jenkins build based on the branch of a git repo. Say I have a git repo with branches A, B, C and D. I need a way to run the Jenkins job merging git branch A and C. This should be triggered when there is any commit made to branches A and C. I know we can specify branches in "Branches to Build", but is there a way to specify the list of branches from a file from a git repo instead of hardcoding in Jenkins? I'm not sure if this can be done, but this would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: I went ahead and used jenkinsfile to create a pipeline job. One step reads a file and gets the branches mentioned in it and merges them. The merged result is used in the next step. The major problem is that the trigger gets started for all branches.